# Django: can I block new entries until one is completed?

Tags: python, django

Sorry for the vague question, here's what's going on:
I will be giving away "win codes" to people. My django app is written so that the first one to enter a valid code XX hours after the last win will again be a winner.
If the user is a winner he will be redirected to a page with a form to claim his prize.
1) User enters code
2) I check the datetime of the last win
3) If it's a winner again, go to the form page

The problem is: if someone wins and then another person enters a code before the first one has filled in the form to claim the prize, the second one will get to that form as well because the last winner is still more than XX hours ago.

How can I avoid this? Can I somehow check if someone already made it to that form?

Comment: There's 100 prizes to win and they're all the same

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Other approach is to write last win datetime right away *in step 3*, so

3) If it's a winner again, create win record and give it (or other form) to user to fill the fields

As mentioned, after some time expiration you can check/remove empty win records

Comment: I ended up adding a claimed_at and a has_won fields to the code model. As soon as someone inputs a valid code, I check when the last winner was, if it was more than XX hours ago, I set the has_won to true, the claimed_at to datetime.now() and the user goes ahead to claim the prize. If it's less than XX hours ago I leave the has_won to false and set claimed_at to datetime.now() to invalidate the submitted code.

Answer (score 0):

You have to create some kind of lock that indicates that the price is currently assigned to a user and that prevents other users from going to the same form.

You could create a random token, store it in the DB (or redis), and add it a hidden field to the form. I suggest you also add an expiration date.

As long as a valid token exists, no other user can access the form. When user 1 submits the form, you check that it contains a valid token.